# How query camunda task just on the intances of the deployment I gave

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

I am using springBoot & camunda.
And I already deploymented two bmpn file. The first called "Test1" and the second called "Test2"

For now I want query task just in the instances of the "Test1" bpmn file exclude the instances of the "Test2" bpmn file.

Can someone tell me how to do it ? please.

Comment: Did you check the api reference? https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/reference/rest/task/

Comment: @christmo Thank you. I already get the info of how to do what I want to do. Just use the   code Like  "taskService.craeteTaskQuery().processDefinitionKey( your key)".

Comment: Cool you could post the answer when you got it. Great work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the java api like below.

```
taskService.createTaskQuery().processDefinitionKey( your process definition key);
```

And then you can do task query only in the process definition instnaces of the key of you gived.